# AngularJS set header on every request

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm trying to set a header to send an access token on every request. This is what I have tried:

```
.factory("TokenRestangular", "StorageService", function (Restangular, StorageService) {
    return Restangular.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {


        // Set access token in header.
        RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHeaders({Authorization:'Bearer '+ StorageService.get("access_token")});
        RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('/api');
    });
})
```

I get the error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%string
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:6:450
    at Bb (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:19:68)
    at Ua (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:19:155)
    at rc (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:32:423)
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:34:398)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:36:288
    at c (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:34:305)
    at d (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:35:6)
    at Object.instantiate (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js:35:165)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your factory function has one too many parameter passed, try this:

```
    .factory("TokenRestangular", function (Restangular, StorageService) {
        return Restangular.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {
        // Set access token in header.
        RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHeaders({Authorization:'Bearer '+ StorageService.get("access_token")});
        RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('/api');
    });
})
```

or

```
    .factory("TokenRestangular", ["Restangular", "StorageService", function (Restangular, StorageService) {
        return Restangular.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {
        // Set access token in header.
        RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHeaders({Authorization:'Bearer '+ StorageService.get("access_token")});
        RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('/api');
    });
}])
```

if you want to have safe minification code.

Comment: My problem is I will refresh the token over time, I successfully get the new token but when I run another RESTful API the token it uses is still the old one.

Comment: @aokaddaoc I dealing with the same problem.. did you solve it ?

Comment: @bitmind Yes I do. https://jsfiddle.net/hcq8sx7p/1/ Hope it can troubleshoot your problem~